# What's the measure of the $\angle PQS$?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, angle

Fr referene:In an inscribed quadrilateral $ABCD, ~P,~ Q, ~and~ S$ are the incenters of the triangles $ABD,~ ABC, ~and ~BCD$, respectively.
Calculate $ \measuredangle PQS $.

My progress:

Here's the drawing I made and the relationships I found..

[image]

Comment: inscribed quadrilateral means that the vertices can be put on a circle. The opposite angles add up to $180^\circ$

Comment: If $\angle PQS$ is constant for all quadrilaterals $ABCD$, then it should be the same as $\angle PQS$ when $ABCD$ is a square of unit 1(say).

Comment: $\measuredangle PQS = 90^0$ for all cyclic quadrilaterals.

Comment: @Aqua..Thanks for the prompt, I will change to plane geometry from now on the tags

Comment: Could anyone demonstrate algebraically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Japanese Theorem (source:https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/CyclicQuadrilateral.shtml#explanation)

[image]

From $
ΔBCD, ∠BI_{BCD}C = 90° + \frac{∠BDC}{2}$

Similarly, from: $ΔABC\rightarrow  ∠BI_{ABC}C = 90° + \frac{∠BAC}{2}$
$ABCD$ is cyclic: $∠BDC = ∠BAC.$

$\therefore ∠BI_{BCD}C = ∠BI_{ABC}C.$

$BI_{ABC}I_{BCD}C \rightarrow$ is cyclic.

$(1) ∠BCI_{BCD} + ∠BI_{ABC}I_{BCD} = 180^\circ$

Similarly the quadrilateral $AI_{ABD}I_{ABC}B$ is cyclic.

$(2) ∠BAI_{ABD} + ∠BI_{ABC}I_{ABD} = 180^\circ$.

From(1) and (2) $\implies ∠BI_{ABC}I_{BCD} + ∠BI_{ABC}I_{ABD} = 360^\circ \frac{∠BCD}{2} - \frac{∠BAD}{2} = 270^o\implies$

$(3) ∠I_{ABD}I_{ABC}I_{BCD} = 90°$